# How to select random value from iOS picker wheel using Selenium

Tags: java, ios, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am performing my automation in real IOS device.
In one of the aspect I have to automate a picker wheel

[image: Image Attached Here]

xpath:

```
//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAPopover[1]/UIAPicker[1]/UIAPickerWheel[1]
```

I would like to select a random value from picker. I can able to do the by sending static value using SendKeys. Instead of the I want to select a random value.

Can I please know how can I do that using java??

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this :

1. Randomise the `UIAPickerWheel[1]` index while you are using the `x-path` to access the elements.
2. You can put all possible static values into an `ArrayList` and use a random element from amongst them to input using the `sendKeys()` in way some-what like this :

   ```
   ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("value1"); 
   list.add("value2"); // so on for all your values
   Random randomizer = new Random();
   String random = list.get(randomizer.nextInt(list.size()));
   element.sendKeys(random);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone would still need this. But just in case this could help somebody out there...

Here's an adaptation of the code in [Nexial Automation](https://nexiality.github.io/documentation/commands/mobile/select(locator,item)):

```
val index = RandomUtils.nextInt(0, 7)
// index = 3

val picker = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//XCUIElementTypePickerWheel"))
val currentPickedValue = picker.getAttribute("value")
val pickerId = picker.id

// if picker already has selection, we'll swipe to top of the dropdown first
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(currentPickedValue))
    driver.executeScript(
        scriptScript,
        mapOf<String, Any>("element" to pickerId, "direction" to "down", "velocity" to 250))

// magic number 25 (per dropdown option)
val scrollAmount = 25.0 / picker.size.height

for (i in 0 until index)
    driver.executeScript(
        scriptSelectPickerValue,
        mapOf<String, Any>("element" to pickerId, "order" to "next", "offset" to scrollAmount))
```

The code is written in Kotlin. If you know Java/JavaScript/C#, then the above should be reasonably comprehensible.

The magic number is derived via some online research and trial-and-error. Seems to work fine so far.

I randomized `index` as an integer between 0 to 7. Feel free to change `index` to something else.

This code has only been tested on XCUITest driver.

Answer (score 0):

Consider moving your view interaction methods to Appium iOS Gestures which does pretty much the same as you did in your script but 'from the box'

[Pickerwheel gesture](https://github.com/appium/appium-xcuitest-driver#mobile-selectpickerwheelvalue-1)